# Any reason to use the least-constrained variable heuristic when searching the solution of a CSP?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, constraint-satisfaction

Is there any (kind of) (well-known) problem which can be expressed as a CSP in which the ***least** constrained variable* heuristic seems to give the best results, when employing backtracking with constraint propagation as the search method?

I am aware of the ***most** constrained variable* heuristic, and the intuition behind it, but I was wondering when one would prefer to use the opposite approach.

Comment: Least constrainED or least constrainING? Least constrained looks like a dumb heuristic, because it starts by taking a variable about which we have very little information and chooses a value for it without knowing what the consequences might be. Does anybody use that? Least constraining, on the other hand, starts by choosing values for the variables that _don't_ seem to have many consequences.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's precisely why I'm asking, and that was my intuition too.  I don't know of anyone using it, nor have I seen it mentioned in any AI (or similar) course.

Comment: OK. I was just confused by your question. Google doesn't seem to return any useful hits for least constrainED, so I wanted to check that you'd not misread least constrainING.